# PHP exec() of bat file returns 0 when ran manually and -1 when ran via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, batch-file, command-line, return-value

I'm getting different $return values based on how I execute a bat file.

When I test a script I have that uses exec($command, $output, $return) to run a bat file by running the script manually with command line I get a 0 for $return and I can see a value in $out as expected. When I run the same script via ajax $return is -1 and $out is a blank array.

I can't find a whole lot of info for negative return values but I'm thinking it's pretty safe to say its saying their is an error - though I'm not sure how to get more info from it that that.

What could be the reason I'm getting different $return values based on how I run the bat file?

Thanks for any advice and assistance.

AJAX Code - I am using ajaxTime to try and see how long the requests are taking. They are varying from usually around 550-650 response time:

```
var ajaxTime = new Date().getTime();
getdSize(f, ajaxTime);

function getSize(f, ajaxTime){
        $.ajax({
            url: "php file handling the ajax request",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                file : encodeURIComponent(f),
                }
            })
        .done(function(data){
            var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
            console.log("Ajax Time: " + totalTime);
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            if ( data.responseCode ){
              console.log( data.responseCode );
            }
            console.log("Ajax failure");
        });
    }
```

PHP Code -

```
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    echo bat_getSize ($file);
[this calls bat_getSize function]

function bat_getSize($file){
    exec("getSize \"$file\"",$out, $ret);
    return $out[0];
}
```

Which calls this
Bat Code -

```
@echo off
echo %~z1
```

Thanks!

***Update***
Am I correct in my understanding that using the .done() callback will prevent my ajax request from being interrupted by the next request sent? Or could that be the failure?

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried so far. Could it have something to do with your AJAX request ?

Comment: Good idea. Sorry I should have done that in the first place. One sec.

Comment: Are the two being executed by the same user?

Comment: Yup. The first part of the php actually calls another php file (I didnt create this, I'm just trying to get it working lol) which then calls the bat file but it is all one user.